# Applying Multi-Context CoreData to an NSOperationQueue-based app

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am still working upon my RSS Reader and though it finally achieves decent functionality, the UI Responsiveness appears to be very bad on an iPad 3.

In order to improve my app, I checked many source on the Internet and fell across [this interesting gem](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/) where Marcus Zarra's approach (having a parent MOC dedicated to saving to the PSC in background) seduced me.

The [example provided by Matthew Morey](https://github.com/mmorey/CoreDataMultiContext) looks gorgeous but does only take a single operation into consideration: the mass-load of entries in an UITableView.

I tried to implement this solution into my app but it's obviously a mess.
I have a MasterViewController which, when starting creates a serie of DBOperation objects which it sends to a serial (1 concurrent max) NSOperationQueue.

Each of my UIViewControllers also perform individual CoreData operations which they save individually (Mark a post as edit, a category as open or closed, etc.).

So, my questions are:

- how (in a nutshell) should I implement a Multi-Contexted CoreData in my app?
- Which controller should add which observer to get their respective UITableView reloaded?
- which controller or delegate should perform the observe NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification/mergechange operation?

I'm really confused by all of this and Markus Zarra's excellent book did help me too little, maybe because I took the wrong way from the very beginning...

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcus S. Zarra actually answers my questions in his excellent ["Core Data 2nd Edition" book](http://pragprog.com/book/mzcd2/core-data) (if you buy only one Core-Data book this year, make it that one!) where he devotes a nice chapter to the concurrency.

What I happened to ignore was how the child/parent relation works with MOCs.

I just learned that a MOC declared with a parent MOC but no PSC will "push" its changes towards its parent whenever its `save` method is invoked.

If our main thread MOC is himself the child of a private "writer" MOC using his own Private queue, then we can cascade the `save` which will be very fast in our main MOC (no disc involved), then delayed in the background in the private writer MOC, thus keeping the GUI responsive.

I also learnt than whenever a MOC uses a private queue, he can only be accessed within a `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` block.

Thanks a lot for your help, Leijonien, you desserved the upvotes!

Answer (score 2):

- You basically need 1 NSManagedObjectContext for each thread.
- Create one context for the main thread, which will be used by all of your viewcontrollers. In the view controllers you can use NSFetchedResultsController, as they will be notified when their data has changed, which can automatically trigger tableview updates.
- Every background thread needs to have it's own managed object context. This context MUST be created in that background thread e.g:

  ```
  NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectConctext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] autorelease];
  [managedObjectConctext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
  managedObjectConctext.undoManager = nil;
  managedObjectConctext.mergePolicy = NSOverwriteMergePolicy;

  return managedObjectConctext;
  ```
- Background threads should therefore only use this context for fetching/updating managed objects. So the most important rule is not accessing managed objects in other threads. (Or fetching in one context and updating in another...)
- The save notification should be implemented on the context in the main thread, as each update in a background context will be merged with the main context, which will trigger your view controllers to update their contents (when appropriate).

Comment: Thanks, where do I implement the (async) writeMOC described by M. Zarra?

Comment: The async save is performed in a background queue, so it doesn't matter where you implement it. Personally i allways put this kind of logic together into one 'CoreDataManager' singleton. In my case the singleton handles the save notifications (and merges), creates contexts for background threads, but also handles automatic migrations when the model has been changed etc...

Comment: ATM this is how my app is working, except with no CoreData Singleton. It still appears to be too slow and unresponsive on the iPad. Would you, by any chance, have a working example of how you do it on github, for example?

Comment: Sure I can put something together, but that would take some time.. I doubt if the 'unresponsiveness' is due to your CoreData implementation. It sounds more like some other task(s) are processing in the main thread (or at least blocking the main thread). Have you been able to track down what your app is doing, when the app is unresponsive. Which thread(s) are causing this? NSLog might help a lot since it will indicate the associated thread for each log.

Comment: I think this could do the trick: https://github.com/adamgit/CoreDataStack but then I digress from M. Zarra's example.